# Creating a search bar application in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to create an application which has a search bar in it. When i start typing in the search bar the text should be displayed in the tableview below. Can anybody please help me with this. I have seen various codes but none is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple released a sample code: [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848). Especially have a look at the MainView.xib. You can see there, how a search bar and a search display controller and the File's owner work together.

See the MainViewController Class, how it changes two different Array.